# What is the latex equivalent of append operation?

Tags: symbols

What is the latex equivalent formula for the append operation of the following code snippet? Is it a union symbol?

```
v = []
for i in range(n):
    v.append(i)
```

Comment: Depends on what v is, macro or name.  `\edef\v{\v.i}` for macro `\v`, `\csname v.i\endcsname` to create name `\v.i`.  Note that this violates naming protocol, so ONLY `\csname` can be used with this name.

Comment: Please show your use-case in (La)TeX.